# check if a value exists or not exists in a sql server database field using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to create a method to know if a value exists in a sql server database field or not using C#, the name of the server is "myServer", the name of database is "myDatabase", the name of table is "myTable ", the name of the field is "myField" and the value is "myValue". I check the following method but it doesn't work :

```
public bool myValueExist(string myTable, string myField, string myValue)
{
        int result = 0;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*) from '" + myTable + "' where'"+myField+"=@myValue", cnx);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myValue", myValue);
        result = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result == 0) return false; 
        else  return true;
}
```

the connection is established to sql server.
Can some one help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service.  At least try something.  If it doesn't work, we can help.  Also try Google.

Comment: Even if this was a free coding service, “Can some one help me?” [is not a question we can answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: To Eric, thank you for your advise, I just forget the my coding part sorry, can you help now?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get an error or does it return true when it should be false etc?

Comment: Your sql command is syntactically incorrect. You're putting single quotes around the tablename (making it a string literal), and you have another quote after the where without a closing quote. I suggest that you debug your code, get the command string and validate it directly against the database, eg. from SSMS.

Comment: The code you have is terrible. First, it's a security hazard since it's an open door to SQL Injection. Second, The one place where do use a parameter, you are doing it wrong. (Using `AddWithValue`). Third, `SqlConnection` should be used as a local variable inside a `using` statement. Microsoft clearly states that it should be closed and disposed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mess of the query string itself. Without a specific error message I can't tell more, but what is obvious is the following.

Assuming `myTable = Foo` and `myField = Bar` your variable of `cmd` would generate to

```
select COUNT(*) from'Foo' where'Bar=@myValue
```

As you can see that is just wrong. It should be

```
select Count(*) from Foo where Bar = @myValue
```

Comment: As an aside from the actual answer, your question needs more specifics. There may be more problems, but a "it doesn't work" doesn't give much to go on. Specific error messages are needed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*) from " + myTable + " where "+ myField + "=@myValue", cnx);
```

Also, using 'using' on SQLConnection, command etc is a good idea for disposing the resources.